# Return error/exception when requested web api formatter is missing

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, asp.net-web-api

Using the following code in my web api initialization I have disabled XmlFormatter so that only json is supported:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Now when a client is making a request using the Accept : application/xml header it will get back json instead of XML. I find this behavior wrong. If a client asks for XML and this is not supported then it should get an UnsupportedMediaType error.

Do you know how I can achieve this in global level in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if Web API cannot determine a formatter using `Accept` or `Content-Type` headers, it will fall back to the first formatter that can serialize your current DTO type - and out of the box, JSON formatter is configured to work with all types, so it will always be the "last resort" fallback.

You can disable that fallback by modifying the `DefaultContentNegotiator`.

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var negotiator = new DefaultContentNegotiator(excludeMatchOnTypeOnly: true);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), negotiator);
```

Once you set `excludeMatchOnTypeOnly` to `true`, Web API will start to issue a 406 response (`Not Acceptable`) to requests for which the formatter cannot be determined - such as the one in your example. This is in line with [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html) which states:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the 300 (Multiple Choices) and 406 (Not Acceptable)
>   status codes for enabling agent-driven negotiation when the server is
>   unwilling or unable to provide a varying response using server-driven
>   negotiation.

You can find a sample VS solution [here](https://github.com/filipw/apress-recipes-webapi/tree/master/Chapter%2006/6-6/Apress.Recipes.WebApi/Apress.Recipes.WebApi).